# Restful API - What to return when no error occurred, but a resource wasn't created?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

For reference, I am referencing http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html while working on this.

I have a Web API 2.2 service that allows a user to add "print requests" with `AddPrintRequest(...)`, then batch those requests using a call to `BatchRequests(...)`.

The `BatchRequests` method validates each request, and batches the valid ones.  If there is at least one valid request, the batch is created and we return a HTTP 201 (Created).  But what should we return if no batch is created?  We don't consider this an error, but want to signal to the client why no batch was created.  What is the correct status code?

Comment: Maybe 204 No Content?

Comment: Hm, maybe so.  I must have misread the description earlier.  Could you submit that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The status `204 No Content` may be suitable here.

Comment: No, I haven't, sorry. Could you maybe rephrase your answer so that it doesn't look like a question?

Comment: @yole: initially it was just comment because I'm not sure myself but OP liked the idea and asked to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Conflict and then throw an exception with a message.

> Equivalent to HTTP status 409. Conflict indicates that the request could not be carried out because of a conflict on the server.

```
var message = "your message here";    
throw new HttpResponseException(
            Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.Conflict, message));
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx